# can we make a for each in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, text

i want to make a program that count the letter A in the texts

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
i = 1
for each a in content:
     i = i + 1``
     print(i)
```

Comment: Python only has a "foreach" loop. That's what the `for` is. If you want to check for a certain character, you'll need to do that manually.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `for` loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this particular task is by using the built-in `count()` function. Then the code becomes:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
print(content.count("A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    i = 0
    for char in f:
        if char == 'a':
            i += 1

print(f'There are {i} a\'s in the txt file.')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string.count(substring)
content.count("a")
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.